# How to run wget in Octave

Tags: matplotlib, octave

I was wondering if there is any way to run wget in octave to download stuff from a URL, similar to how you would run !wget in C++ or Python

Comment: There's [urlread/write](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/URL-Manipulation.html) for general files. If you're reading images, you can just put the URL directly in `imread`.

Comment: you can also use `system`  https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Controlling-Subprocesses.html#Controlling-Subprocesses